# Android Studio 3.0 Gradle sync failed: java.lang.AssertionError (in UnresolvedDependenciesReporter)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When migrating to Android Studio 3.0-beta1, I am running into a gradle sync failed error that does not provide much info. There is no error message in the gradle console. I had to go to the idea.log file to get the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:174)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:155)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.data.service.ModuleModelDataService.importData(ModuleModelDataService.java:80)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.data.service.ModuleModelDataService.importData(ModuleModelDataService.java:50)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.doImportData(ProjectDataManager.java:246)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:143)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:198)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManager.importData(ProjectDataManager.java:204)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.doSelectiveImport(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:206)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.populate(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:156)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.access$000(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask$1.run(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.issues.UnresolvedDependenciesReporter.report(UnresolvedDependenciesReporter.java:79)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.issues.SyncIssuesReporter.report(SyncIssuesReporter.java:86)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.issues.SyncIssuesReporter.report(SyncIssuesReporter.java:71)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.android.DependenciesAndroidModuleSetupStep.doSetUpModule(DependenciesAndroidModuleSetupStep.java:98)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.android.DependenciesAndroidModuleSetupStep.doSetUpModule(DependenciesAndroidModuleSetupStep.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.ModuleSetupStep.setUpModule(ModuleSetupStep.java:34)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.module.AndroidModuleSetup.setUpModule(AndroidModuleSetup.java:44)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.data.service.AndroidModuleModelDataService.setUpModule(AndroidModuleModelDataService.java:93)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.data.service.AndroidModuleModelDataService.importData(AndroidModuleModelDataService.java:79)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.data.service.ModuleModelDataService$1.run(ModuleModelDataService.java:78)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$Simple.run(WriteCommandAction.java:234)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$null$1(WriteCommandAction.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1023)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$performWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$doExecuteCommand$4(WriteCommandAction.java:210)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.doExecuteCommand(WriteCommandAction.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$execute$0(WriteCommandAction.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransactionAndWait$2(TransactionGuardImpl.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:109)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:410)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:399)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:655)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I followed the [migration documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) but still can't get the sync to run successfully. Not sure if this is an issue in Android Studio 3.0-beta1 or my project configuration. I have run other projects and created new ones with Android Studio 3.0-alphaX so leaning towards my project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue was I did not select defaults for missing build types. My project has 2 modules with the following build types configuration:

data/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug { ... }
        release { ... }
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug { ... }
        dev { ... }
        qa { ... }
        rc { ... }
        release { ... }
    }
}
```

With the latest Android gradle plugin, your build types must match from library to application modules. My issue was my data module did not define `dev`,`qa`, and `rc` build types. I resolved this by using `buildTypeMatching` in my application module:

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    ...

    buildTypeMatching 'dev', 'debug'
    buildTypeMatching 'qa', 'debug'
    buildTypeMatching 'rc', 'release'

    buildTypes {
        debug { ... }
        dev { ... }
        qa { ... }
        rc { ... }
        release { ... }
    }
}
```

You could also add the missing variants to the library modules as well.

I came across this [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64575098) which seemed to be my same issue. Looks like there is a bug in the error messaging which hopefully will get fixed.

Answer (score 10):

Just turn off offline mode. It's works for me.

Comment: Thanks man! Forgot that on on a flight, it was driving me crazy

Answer (score 6):

In my case restarting Android Studio solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

Try to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

- **Build -> Clean project**

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue but for me it was because I forgot to initialize my git submodules which resulted in one android module not beeing there throwing the same error...

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me as well. Turns out it is the same reason as kyhule, the buildTypes in different module gradle have to be exactly match.

Just want to add a point that it will be easier to find out where the error is by building the gradle from terminal with command line `./gradlew build`. It will provide more useful information that you can follow to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I got a similar error, it turned out I needed to use a newer version of Android Studio. I got this error when I was using Android Studio 3 Canary 2, but then I used the latest beta and this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the event log showed:

```
2:18 PM Project setup started

2:18 PM Gradle sync failed: EventQueue.isDispatchThread()=false Toolkit.getEventQueue()=com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue@40306e17
                Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 3,4,Idea Thread Group] 1439896692
                SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,Idea Thread Group] 519777864 (2 s 913 ms)

2:18 PM Syncing only active variant
                You can disable this experimental feature from
                File → Settings → Experimental → Gradle → Only sync the active variant
```

I tried everything, but sure enough, I just had to do what it said and uncheck "Only sync the active variant" checkbox. Not sure how it got checked in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by following the given steps:-

1. Go to SDK Manager(Ctrl+Shift+A then type SDK Manager).
2. Go to SDK Tools
3. Deselect or uninstall all SDK Tools except for Android Support Repository and Android SDK Platform-Tools
4. Try again to sync the project.