# Android Studio 3.0 Gradle sync failed: java.lang.AssertionError

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, build.gradle

When migrating to Android Studio 3.0-beta2, I am running into a gradle sync failed error that does not provide much info. There is no error message in the gradle console, just prints **"Gradle sync failed: java.lang.AssertionError (17s 671ms)"**

Comment: At least post your build.gradle

Comment: build.gradle is ok, its not build.gradle problem

Comment: The build.gradle can be involed in this kind of error. With this info is quite impossibile to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn off offline mode.

It's hard to find solution, because if there is need to turn off offline mode, Android Studio mentions it as a solution. But for this case it prints **"Gradle sync failed: java.lang.AssertionError (17s 671ms)"**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640245/android-studio-3-0-gradle-sync-failed-java-lang-assertionerror-in-unresolvedde