# Multiline Print in Android text view crashing my app

Tags: java, android

Logcat Image
[image: Logcat Image]

Below is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    assert bundle != null;
    ArrayList<String> expTit = bundle.getStringArrayList("expTit");
    ArrayList<Integer> expAmt =bundle.getIntegerArrayList("expAmt");
    TextView t= findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView t2= findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (expTit == null) throw new AssertionError();
    String text="";
    for (String details : expTit) {
        text = text + details + "\n";
    }
    t.setText(text);
}
```

Here the arraylist comes from another activity. When I press the button to go to this activity the app crashes. Why is that?

Comment: Post your logcat.

Comment: Welcome to SO! *crashing my app* will print something on the logcat, So please show us that, otherwise Icannot help

Comment: I have added image so if you could help

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: @SandeepParish do you want the app one or the project one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640245/android-studio-3-0-gradle-sync-failed-java-lang-assertionerror-in-unresolvedde

Answer (score 1):

Your logcat image clearly states that exception crashing your app is a AssertionError, meaning that the line

```
assert bundle != null;
```

or the line

```
if (expTit == null) throw new AssertionError();
```

is the one crashing your app. So basically your Intent extras bundle is null or the expTit is null.

Comment: Hello there i have a array list to be filled in another activity and from that activity i have sent that array list by using intent so this error is coming can you help me resolve this error